# Почему telegram_bot не отвечает на запрос из Colab?

Tags: python, telebot, google-colaboratory

Установлена библиотека `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`
далее след код

```
import telebot

# Здесь нужно вставить токен, который дал BotFather при регистрации
# Пример: token = ''
token = ''  # <<< Ваш токен

# В этой строчке мы заводим бота и даем ему запомнить токен
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

# Пишем первую функцию, которая отвечает "Привет" на команду /start
# Все функции общения приложения с ТГ спрятаны в функции под @
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def say_hi(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')

# Запускаем бота. Он будет работать до тех пор, пока работает ячейка
# (крутится значок слева).
# Остановим ячейку - остановится бот
bot.polling()
```

В Телеграме после ввода `/start` выдает общее меню, а должен `Привет`.
Библиотека грузит python 3.10

Ранее был установлен Pycharm с версией python 3.12
Может в этом дело?

Comment: В колабе вполне могут быть порты телеги перекрыты.

Comment: Спасибо! Похоже, что так. Из Pycharm тож пробовал - таж история